# How can we compare values in Objective-C like in PHP?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode4

I am trying to compare the annotation title with title values to put different annotation image for different annotations. I tried to compare like in PHP:

```
if(title == "parking" || title = "car")
{
}
```

in Objective C I tried to do it like:

```
if([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Parking" || [annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Peace Hall" ] )
{
}
```

but it did not work. How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: figured out the problem :P 
     if([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Parking"] || [[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Peace Hall" ] )
{
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just messed up the syntax. Try this:

```
if([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Parking"] || [[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Peace Hall"] ) {
    /* Code */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

`if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Parking" || [annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Peace Hall"])`

to:

`if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Parking"] || [[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Peace Hall"])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to send each `isEqualToString:` message separately, i.e.

```
if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Parking"] || [[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Peace Hall"])
{
}
```